# can I use xml wire with java annotation in spring

Tags: spring

I have a class of GenerateKey which is for spring mvc boot. Since it needs to contact database and message queue, so I tried to wire it using xml

```
@RestController
public class GenerateKey {
    final private DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;
    final private AmqpTemplate rabbitMQTemplate;
    final private String queueName;
    public GenerateKey(DriverManagerDataSource dataSource,AmqpTemplate rabbitMQTemplate,String queueName){
        this.dataSource=dataSource;
        this.rabbitMQTemplate =rabbitMQTemplate;
        this.queueName =queueName;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/key/generate")
    public String generateKey(@RequestParam(value = "businesskey") String businesskey, @RequestParam(value = "customer") String customer, Model model) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbctemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("businesskey", businesskey);
        obj.put("customer", customer);
        rabbitMQTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, obj.toString());
        System.out.println(businesskey+customer);
        return "greeting" + businesskey + customer;
    }
}
```

the xml configurations is as the following and using
 `@ImportResource( { "rabbit-listener-context.xml" } )` 
to import it

```
 <bean id="request" class="com.testcom.keyservice.GenerateKey" c:dataSource-ref="dataSource" c:rabbitMQTemplate-ref="keyRequestTemplate" c:queueName="${keyRequestQueueName}"/>
```

but it complain "No default constructor found" as following:

```
2014-11-26 21:42:16.095  INFO 17400 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2014-11-26 21:42:16.097 ERROR 17400 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'generateKey' defined in file [/home/oracle/NetBeansProjects/rabbitmq-native/keyService/build/classes/main/com/testcom/keyservice/GenerateKey.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.testcom.keyservice.GenerateKey]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.testcom.keyservice.GenerateKey.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
Exception in thread "main"  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicatixt.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
```

Comment: There is no default constructor and the constructor you have isn't annotated with `@Autowired`. The main problem is that you have XML configuration and a `@RestController` which leads to 2 instances of the bean, why do you need the XML one, just let it be detected. IMHO your class is flawed first don't depend on `DriverManagerDataSource` but `DataSource` and don't construct a `JdbcTemplate` each time you need one just construct it once and keep it. Or even better use the spring-boot created one and just inject it (instead of the datasource and constructing yuor own.

Comment: @M.Deinum, good suggestion. But how to construct JdbcTemplate only once? Every time a URLrequest to GenerateKey, will a new instance created so that JdbcTemplate initialized many times? If so how to keep one instance? if spring reuse the same instance of GenerateKey for each URLrequest, then it only init one JdbcTemplate.

Comment: A `JdbcTemplate` is a heavy object to construct as it does detection of database type and tries to construct several other things. After construction it is thread safe so simply reuse it. You only have a single instance of your `GenerateKey` class (well actually two at the moment) but the scope of the bean is singleton so no new instance per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Spring Boot I assume you have also `@ComponentScan` active in your application. Because of that you create two instances of `GenerateKey` class - once because of `@RestController` annotation, second time in XML. I believe that's not what you want to achieve.

Get rid of XML declaration of `request` bean representing `GeneratorKey` class and use only Java based autowiring.

```
@RestController
public class GenerateKey {
    private final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;
    private final AmqpTemplate rabbitMQTemplate;
    private final String queueName;

    @Autowired
    public GenerateKey(@Qualifier("dataSource") DriverManagerDataSource dataSource, @Qualifier("keyRequestTemplate") AmqpTemplate rabbitMQTemplate, @Value("${keyRequestQueueName}") String queueName) {
        this.dataSource=dataSource;
        this.rabbitMQTemplate =rabbitMQTemplate;
        this.queueName =queueName;
    }
```

Comment: M. Deinum also commented "don't construct a JdbcTemplate each time you need one just construct it once and keep it. Or even better use the spring-boot created one and just inject it (instead of the datasource and constructing yuor own.", does your approach use spring-boot created one and just inject it (instead of the datasource and constructing yuor own?Sorry I am newbie to spring.

Comment: My answer only show how to properly instantiate your beans and autowire dependencies. @m-deinum is totally right - there are more issues with your code. I suggest getting familiar with Spring Boot reference and many many Spring guides. Good luck and have fun with Spring!